# How to apply Sub-surf on cloth sim

Tags: cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface

i was trying to make a room art and was making a sofa , but when i appplied the subsurf , this happened

[image]

how to fix this

Comment: The modifier tab doesn't show the subsurf modifier, did you apply it to the cloth?

Comment: yes i applied it

Comment: it was because you applied the subsurf before the cloth simulation. See the error message saying "Applied modifier was not first. Result might not be as expected". To confirm it I recreated the same and got somewhat similar result